# Howto do a sub request in same transaction in TomEE?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, transactions, ejb, apache-tomee

In TomEE (preferable with container managed transactions) I want to do a sub request and use its output in my current request, but both must be part of the same transaction. All (even wild ideas, but preferable only using standard API's and not TomEE specific) are welcome how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This stackoverflow question provided a hint to answer my question: [Acessing Remote/Local Session Beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158023/acessing-remote-local-session-beans)

Thanks to a colleague I got it working with TomEE with in the following way:

Structure is to have two web applications and an interface jar:

1. AppA. Exposes a RESTfull web service that calls out to a stateless
   session bean (BeanA) that reuses a stateless session bean from AppB.
   This is built as a WAR.
2. AppB. Exposes a stateless session bean
   BeanB. This is built as a WAR.
3. AppBItf. Contains the local interface
   of BeanB. This is built as a JAR, which is to be shared among AppA
   and AppB.

**Content of AppA**

In AppA, we have three things: The REST service, the bean and its local interface.
*RestService.java*

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/RestService/")
public class RestService
{
    @EJB
    BeanALocal bean;

    @GET
    @Path("/doInTransaction")
    public Response doInTransaction() {
        return Response.ok().entity("Transaction result: " + bean.doInTransaction()).build();
    }
}
```

*BeanA.java*

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry;
import BeanBLocal;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class BeanA implements BeanALocal
{
    @EJB
    BeanBLocal beanB;
    @Resource
    TransactionSynchronizationRegistry txReg;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public String doInTransaction() {
        return "Transaction: " + txReg.getTransactionKey() + "; BeanB: " + beanB.doInTransaction();
    }
}
```

*BeanALocal.java*

```
import javax.ejb.Local;
@Local
public interface BeanALocal {
    String doInTransaction();
}
```

**Content of AppB**

This contains only the bean (its local interface is defined in AppBItf):

*BeanB.java*

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class BeanB implements BeanBLocal
{
    @Resource
    TransactionSynchronizationRegistry txReg;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public String doInTransaction() {
        return "BeanB: Transaction: " + txReg.getTransactionKey();
    }
}
```

**Content of AppBItf**

This contains just the local interface of BeanB:

*BeanBLocal.java*

```
import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface BeanBLocal {
    String doInTransaction();
}
```

Deployment

The two WARs (AppA.war and AppB.war) can simply be deployed to webapps, but the JAR (AppBItf) needs to be added to the common class loader (common.loader).

Outcome

In the above code, BeanB is annotated with TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED. Invoking the REST service (i.e. doing a GET on http://localhost:8080/AppA/RestService/doInTransaction) results in the following output:

```
 [Xid:globalId=1000000047544d4944,length=64,branchId=0,length=64];
 [Xid:globalId=1000000047544d4944,length=64,branchId=0,length=64]
```

Note that the first and second transaction ID are identical, so the transaction of BeanA is reused by BeanB. This is what I required.

When I change the annotation into TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW, the container automatically starts a new transaction for BeanB:

```
[Xid:globalId=1000000047544d4944,length=64,branchId=0,length=64];
[Xid:globalId=2000000047544d4944,length=64,branchId=0,length=64]
```

The ID of the first transaction starts with 1, while the second starts with 2.